# Notion Database ID Not Working in Make Integration

Tags: notion-api

I have a databse in Notion that I'm trying to integrate with my Google Calendar via a 2 way sync in Make. I set up the integration from this example: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ooEFXonGCsA though mine is a bit different, the main issue is that my database id returns as invalid everytime. The issue is listed as a Notion issue and not a Make error.

I followed this [stack overflow query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67728038/where-to-find-database-id-for-my-database-in-notion#fromHistory), the 'long-hash 1' returns invalid. I tried the 2nd long hash: invalid. I tried the entire link: invalid. I don't know why the string keeps returning as invalid. Can someone please help with this?

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, it could be because there's sometimes a delay of 1 hour before all pages and databases show up. Read it here >> https://www.reddit.com/r/NotionforBusiness/comments/owk5cl/integromat_doesnt_see_my_databases/

Fingers crossed :)