# How can I retrieve the Database for the "Getting Started" node using the Notion API?

Tags: notion-api

I am writing an integration and would like it to traverse the database space in a users home. For this, I would like to obtain the properties of the `Getting Started` node, which for my user looks like this:

```
https://www.notion.so/Getting-Started-7da6eba0d8a2416b80349c6cea7806f0
```

I am wondering how given a user object, I can navigate to this node to obtain the database ID for it. This use-case is special because database urls usually [look like this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67728038/where-to-find-database-id-for-my-database-in-notion)

```
https://www.notion.so/<long_hash_1>?v=<long_hash_2>
```

with `long_hash_1` being the required ID.

Is it not possible to access a database like `Getting Started`?

I have tried the full segment (`Getting-Started-7da6eba0d8a2416b80349c6cea7806f0`) and the UUID part of the URL (`7da6eba0d8a2416b80349c6cea7806f0`) as parameters. I have also looked around for other URLs for this page.

I would have expected that the above would be resolved to the database.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that using the UUID is correct, but that formatting matters:
`7da6eba0d8a2416b80349c6cea7806f0` needs to be formatted `7da6eba0-d8a2-416b-8034-9c6cea7806f0`.

I have found this out by querying the [Search by title](https://developers.notion.com/reference/post-search) endpoint with the `Getting Started` key string. It returned the formatted ID.

Answer (score 0):

This [sample](https://github.com/makenotion/notion-sdk-js/blob/main/examples/generate-random-data/index.ts#L376) obtains this information using a filter. However, the iterator returned does not contain the non-user generated entry.

Answer (score 0):

The `Getting Started` Node is a page. It can be found by using the Search endpoint with the filter set to the object type `page`.

Root pages have the workspace as a parent, as seen below. Post-processing allows to find these.

```json
            "parent": {
                "type": "workspace",
                "workspace": true
            },
```